# How to set Cmder as default cmd (console) in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, cmder

When running console applications from Visual Studio (not Code), I would like to use Cmder instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try adjusting these settings:

In `Integration > Default Term`, select the `Force ConEmu as default terminal for console applications` checkbox:

[image: Force ConEmu as default option in Cmder settings]

Then, point the applications you wish to use via Cmder in the `List of hooked executables` section. In your case, since you want to use Cmder as the default in Visual Studio, you would add `|devenv.exe` into the list below:

[image: Adding parent apps to use Cmder as default]

Save these settings, possibly restart your computer, and it should open a new Cmder tab the next time you run the console in Visual Studio.

[More Info and Options Here](https://conemu.github.io/en/DefaultTerminal.html)